# Asp.net webforms C# file compile

Tags: asp.net, web, compilation

I have an asp.net 4.0 webforms application. It is a website, not a project, so it is not precompiled before deployment.

I made a change to a single code-behind file (c# file) and I need to upload it to the website. If I upload just this single file, will it compile on the website? Or do I need to upload other files to trigger a compile? E.g., do I need to upload the front end .aspx file along with it?

I ask this because a change that I made works on my dev machine but isn't working on the production server. I suspect that perhaps, the C# file that was uploaded hasn't compiled on the web server, thus, the website is still running the older c# file.

Anyone have thoughts on this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I should specify that it is a **website project**, not a web application project.

Comment: If you are using a website project that isn't precompiled, you should be able to update it per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx#compilation.  

Have you tried recycle the site? (use judgement as that will kill any sessions, possibly cache, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clarify this. You made changes in your ASP.NET page from code behind. Now, you want to upload this new changes to the server. Is that correct?

Okay, you simply upload the updated .ASPX page (and of course its code-behind file automatically) to the server and replace the old .ASPX page. The changes to that particular page should appear now. It has nothing to do if you pre-compile or not your website.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to compile it again. Your web application should be updated once you've uploaded the new file. Most probably cache issue. Try using a different browser or clear the cache on current browser.

Comment: Sorry, i made an edit to OP. It is a website project, not a web application project. Website projects are deployed and compile on the web server dynamically when it is run the first time. My issue is, how does one code behind file compile once it is uploaded at a later time. Does it need something to trigger it? Not sure if this makes a difference in your answer.

Comment: @nanonerd Recompile will get triggered based on the change in modified date of the file.

Answer (score 0):

As you upload new CS files on a Website project on the production server, it should recompile them dynamically allowing the changes to be picked up.  Is there a possibility that its on a Farm and all the servers weren't updated?

Comment: this happens sometimes in server farms - one server get updated other do not.

Comment: Are you running on IIS in the cloud or a Linux/ mono solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer. And I apologize as it probably should not have even been asked. H. Javier is correct above as I found out this morning (before seeing his answer).

Sorry, it turned out that my colleague was uploading to the wrong directory on the web server ... and I couldn't see what was happening ... it's a long winded story but I was working remotely and didn't have direct access to the web server myself.

But hey, for anyone that is curious, I simply uploaded the code-behind (myFile.aspx.cs) file and the asp.net engine did its magic and it worked. So no need to upload other files (like the front end myFile.aspx nor the web.config) to force a compile. It happens automatically.

Thank you.